# Proof of bijectivity of a certain function

Tags: functions, proof-verification

**The task:**

Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a function:

Show that when there exists a function $f^{-1}: Y\longrightarrow X$, so that:

$f\circ f^{-1} = id_Y \wedge f^{-1}\circ f = id_X$.

so is $f$ bijective.

**My proof/reasoning:**

When there are the functions $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ and $f^{-1}: Y\longrightarrow X$,
we can define:

$f^{-1}(Y):= X \wedge f(X) := Y$

Looking at the composition:

$f\circ f^{-1} = id_Y $ we can write $f: Y \longrightarrow X \longrightarrow Y$

The first part of the composition $f^{-1}: Y \longrightarrow X$ can be written as $f^{-1}(Y) = X $

since a function requires, that for every $y\in Y$ there can only be one $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$ this statement implies that $|Y| \ge |f^{-1}(Y)|$ so the cardinality of the sets is either the same or $Y$ has an bigger cardinality.

Looking at the second part of the composition:

$f:f^{-1}(Y)\longrightarrow Y$

we can again claim, that a function requires that for every $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$ there can only be one $y\in Y$.
This statement implies that $|f^{-1}(Y)| \ge |Y| $ and from

$|Y| \ge |f^{-1}(Y)|$ $\wedge$ $|f^{-1}(Y)| \ge |Y| $ $\Longrightarrow$ $|Y| = |f^{-1}(Y)| = |X|$

projecting this on our function $f^{-1}: Y\longrightarrow X$, we can say that $f^{-1}(Y)=X$ is bijective since the cardinality of both sets is the same and the function requires that for every $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$ there can only be exactly one $y\in Y$.
When $f^{-1}$ is bijective $\Longrightarrow f$ bijective aswell.

I hope you guys can tell me if my reasoning is correct or how it should be altered :) thanks

Comment: “proofing” is what you do to prepare an engraving or a text, or what you do when reviewing galley proofs prior to printing. “Proving” is what you do when you prove something.

Comment: Having the same cardinality does not imply any injection is bijective or any surjective is a bijection; that is only true for finite sets. Your argument that the given function is a bijection seems to rely on showing the functions are one-to-one and the sets have the same cardinality, and if so, the reasoning is flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us prove it in a more readable way.

You want to show that $f$ is one-to- one and onto.

$$ f(x)=f(y) \implies f^{-1}(f(x))=f^{-1}(f(y))\implies id_X(x)=id_X(y) \implies x=y$$
That is the $f$ is one-to-one.

Now let $y\in Y$ be an arbitrary element.$$y=f(f^{-1}(y))=f(x)$$

Where $x=f^{-1}(y)$

That proves that $f$ is onto.

Thus  $f$ is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

First, I will give you a Lemma that can help you do the result. After, I will write my comments on your write-up.

> **Lemma.** Let $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to Z$ be functions.
>
> 1. If $g\circ f$ is one-to-one, then $f$ is one-to-one.
> 2. If $g\circ f$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective.
> 3. If $g\circ f$ is bijective, then $f$ is one-to-one and $g$ is surjective.

*Proof.* 1. Suppose $a,b\in X$ are such that $f(a)=f(b)$. We want to prove that $a=b$. Since $f(a)=f(b)$, then $g\circ f(a) = g(f(a))= g(f(b))= g\circ f(b)$. Since we are assuming $g\circ f$ is one-to-one, it follows from $g\circ f(a)=g\circ f(b)$ that $a=b$, which is what we wanted to prove.

2. Let $z\in Z$. We want to show that there exists $y\in Y$ such that $g(y)=z$. Since $g\circ f$ is surjective, we know that there exists $x\in X$ such that $g\circ f(x) = z$. Let $y= f(x)$. Then $g(y)= g(f(x)) = g\circ f(x) = z$. Thus, $g$ is surjective and we are done.
3. If $g\circ f$ is bijective, the it is one-to-one, so by (1) we know that $f$ is one-to-one. Since $g\circ f$ is bijective, the it is surjective, so we know that $g$ is surjective. $\Box$

Can we say more in (3)? No. Consider $X=\{x\}$, $Y=\{a,b\}$, $Z=\{z\}$ $f\colon X\to Y$ given by $f(x) = a$, and $g\colon Y\to Z$ given by $g(a)=g(b)=z$. Then $g\circ f\colon X\to Z$ maps $x$ to $z$, and is bijective. But $f$ is not surjective and $g$ is not one-to-one.

Now, if $f\colon X\to Y$ has an inverse $f^{-1}\colon Y\to X$, then as you note we have that $f^{-1}\circ f = \mathrm{id}_X$ (which is bijective); and that $f\circ f^{-1}=\mathrm{id}_Y$ (which is bijective). Hence....

---

> “We can define $f(X)=Y\wedge f^{-1}(Y)=X$.”

You are not “defining” things. The functions $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are given. Now, saying that $f(X)=Y$ is equivalent to saying $f$ is surjective... which is one of the things you were supposed to prove. So you need to justify it. (Also, note that technically these are not $f$ and $f^{-1}$, but rather the induced functions on subsets of $X$ and $Y$).

Now, you can *justify* these assertions (which are **conclusions**, not *definitions*) for example by noting that the fact that $f\circ f^{-1}=\mathrm{id}_Y$ means that the image of the composituym $f\circ f^{-1}$ is all of $Y$, and in general the image of a composition $h\circ g$ is contained in the image of $h$. So here you have 
$$Y =f\circ f^{-1}(Y) \subseteq f(X) \subseteq Y,$$
giving equality, and similarly with $f^{-1}$. But you should not just affirm this, and you certainly should not say “define”.

> The first part of the composition can be written as $f^{-1}(Y)=X$.

No; this is an assertion that $f^{-1}$ is surjective; you need to justify it. You don’t get it simply from the fact that you have a composition, or from the fact that $f^{-1}$ has domain $Y$ and codomain $X$.

> since a function requires that for every $y\in Y$ there be only one $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$ this statement implies $|Y|\geq |f^{-1}(Y)|$

This is just not right. “fir every $y\in Y$ there is only one $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$ (presumably “such that $f^{-1}(y)=x$”) is just the definition of function. But in order to make a conclusion about cardinalities, you need to know the function is either surjective or one-to-one. The “only one” seems to imply that you are trying to make an argument about cardinality stemming form one-to-one-ness (though you have not established this); but in that case, you would get $|Y|\leq |f^{-1}(Y)| \leq |X|$ which is exactly the **opposite** inequality to the one you are claiming.

You then make the same mistake with $f$.

And finally, you conclude that $|X|=|Y|$, and use that to conclude that $f$ is bijective. You can’t do that. Even if you had already established that $f$ is surjective (you haven’t), or one-to-one (you haven’t), that together with cardinality is not enough, because in the infinite case, neither of the two conditions suffices. For example, the map $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(x)=2x$ is one-to-one, domain and codomain have the same cardinality, but $f$ is not bijective. And the map $f\colon \mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by $g(x)=x$ if $x\lt 1$ and $g(x) = x-1$ if $x\geq 1$ is surjective, domain and codomain have the same cardinality, but $g$ is not surjective.

So I’m afraid this is no good: you are making assertions without warrant, and even if you had justified all of these assertions, the path you are trying to take **cannot** be used to establish that $f$ is bijective. You’ll have to try something else.